# where does a django file upload is stored?

Tags: python, django

If I create a django form that permits a user to upload a file, where does the file get stored or where do I configure it from. I am using the development server porvided by django.
Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers can be found in [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/file-uploads/).

If the file is small enough, it's stored in **memory**. If not, it's saved under the `FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR` directory (`/tmp` by default on Unix systems).

You can completely customize the upload process by writing **your own upload handlers** (once again, it's in the link above).

I don't believe there are real differences between the dev server and a prod environment on this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i still don't understand what does memory really mean. is there a specific location? i have the following function that handles the file upload  def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('/home/dutzy/Desktop/mysite/asta.txt', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
i know the upload works because i see that the destination file is written. but is there a specific location where the original file is stored? thank you

Comment: @Bigdeinrock, "memory" means that if the file is < 2.5 megs, Django never saves the uploaded file to disk (to your hard-drive), it just keeps it in RAM.